# Xampp - MySQL can't create/write to file (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, windows-7, phpmyadmin, xampp

**Edit** More information:

I'm trying to run a MySQL query via an event in phpMyAdmin and I'm getting the error above. More specifically, I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [root@localhost][ally.send_stories] Can't create/write to file '\xampp\tmp\stories.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Here is a dumbed down query. The actual one uses joins

```
begin
select * into outfile '/xampp/tmp/stories.csv' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '/n' from my_table where date_added between date_sub(now(), interval 7 day) and now();
end
```

I've looked into this and from what I can tell, it's due to not having write permissions to the director. The trouble is, I'm not exactly sure how to give mysql write access to the director it needs.

Currently I'm just using the default root@localhost

**Edit**
I'm Running this as an Event in phpMyAdmin - locally (currently)

Comment: Please give the config.php file where you are connecting to the db.

Comment: @AmitKumar Sorry - I should have mentioned that I'm running this as an event from phpMyAdmin. Unless you mean a different config file.

Comment: Which action are you trying to execute exactly ?

Comment: @Polymorphin: outfile. The idea is to run a query and save it to a .csv file. Eventually I'll be trying to email that file, but I need to get it to write it first ;)

Comment: And in which directory are you trying to save the csv file?

Comment: @Polymorphin: I've updated my post to give more information. Currently /xampp/tmp/ but I have tried using /tmp as I read somewhere that it defaults to the xampp/mysql/DATABASE_DIRECTORY/ but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you tried another path?

Comment: I tried /xampp/tmp, /xampp/mysql/tmp, /xampp/mysql/data/tmp, and /xampp/mysql/data/database_name/tmp - none of which seemed to work.

Comment: Ok apparently removing the path and just using the filename.csv, it executes fine - into /xampp/mysql/data/database_name/filename.csv. Creating a tmp folder in there and using /tmp/filename.csv or tmp/filname.csv results in the same previous error.

Comment: @Polymorphin while I haven't solved the problem of writing to a directory, your reply did lead me being to save the file to the default location. If you'd like credit, feel free to create a post that I can mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try another path it should solve your problem.